# How can I find a Post of a User?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I want to find posts which user has made ..

I do my request with JWT Token:

```
###
http://localhost:8080/forum/getByOwnerID
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}
```

This is my create function :

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
 
  const { forumName, forumDescription } = req.body;
  const token = req.token;
  const forumExist = await Forum.findOne({ forumName: req.body.forumName });
  if(forumExist){
    res.status(400).send("Forum Exists already.");
  }  
  try{
  const owner = await User.findOne({userID:token._id});
  if (!forumName || !forumDescription) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please Fill all the feilds");
    return;
  }
  else {
    const newForum = new Forum({ forumName, forumDescription,user: owner.userID });
    newForum.user = owner;
    const createdNote = await newForum.save();
    res.status(201).json(createdNote);
  }
  }catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
};
```

This is my function where I want to get the Posts which the user has made :

```
exports.getByToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const forum = await Forum.findById( {user: req.token._id} );

  if (forum) {
    res.json(forum);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "Forum not found" });
  }

  res.json(forum);
}
```

And this is model which I have for Post:

```
const forumSchema = ({
    forumName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    forumDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    user: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        
        ref: 'user'
    },
    published_on: {
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("LLL")
    },
});
```

Everytime I do a request it has this error :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ user: 'admin' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "Forum"
```

my generate Token :

```
const generateToken = (_id, userID) => {
  console.log('Signing token for ID ', _id,userID);
  console.log('Secret key is ', process.env.JWT_KEY);
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id,userID}, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });
  console.log('Signed token: ', token);
  return token;
  
};
```

Comment: You should use [.findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead of (.findById())[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById] because your search criteria isn't ID itself: `const forum = await Forum.findOne({ user: req.token._id })`

Comment: @Xeelley this is not working :/

Comment: If you wanna get user as a result, why are you searching through Forum<>User relation? Is there any reason why you can't search using user schema directly? Also "admin" isn't an `ObjectId`, is it primary key of user schema?

Comment: I don´t want to get a user as a result. I want to get the post which the user made. I can get all posts or get post by the id of the post but I can´t get the post by given token.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about: `"admin"` doesn't looks like token, also I believe token isn't a user schema primary key because of `.findOne` doesn't work too.

Comment: @Xeelley what should I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById), you should only send the id as argument function.

If you want to search with filter query, use [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) method

Comment: Doesn´t change anything ...

Comment: req.token._id === 'admin'. Is this the correct id? You should send an objectId. Something like:

await Forum.findById("61ae5a282b95e28f371cd0b9");

Comment: But I want to find by token ..

Comment: Your decoded token payload has to have the value that you should use to find your document. If this value is the ObjectId, use findById and pass it as argument. If it is another field, use findOne as you use here: await Forum.findOne({ forumName: req.body.forumName })

Comment: Also, ensure that you are including this value when you create the jwt, in the sign in process.

Comment: I edit my generate Token .. if you want to see

Comment: If _id is the document id, FindById(_id) should work. Check if req.token._id has the correct value. Is your middleware setting the payload on req.token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240138/discussion-between-basics-typer-and-andresf).

Comment: I will put it in another answer ok ?